# problem with function give me always undefined

Tags: javascript

An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or non-consecutive. Implement a function that determines whether a string that contains only letters is an isogram. Assume the empty string is an isogram. Ignore letter case.

and this is my answer.

```java
function isIsogram(str){

      var strArray = str.toString().split('') 

      for(var i = 0; str.length < i ; i++ ) {

      if (strArray[i] == strArray[0]) 
    return false;
     return true;

      }
}
```

Comment: `strArray[i] == strArray[0]` doesn't make much sense because the first iteration `i` will always be `0` so you are comparing `strArray[0] == strArray[0]` which is always true. (And because you use `return` in your if, it will exit your function immediately.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are testing if the characters are equal to the first character in a string. If they are then you return false and else true. Now this is a wrong logic. You need to check individual characters against the rest of the characters in the string. In the most basic sense you need to run a nested loop.

Here is one way to approach the problem.

```
function isIsogram(str){
   var i, j; //declaring two variables to assist in nested loop
   str = str.toLowerCase(); //making the string convert to lowercase because a===A will return false
   for(i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) { //first loop to select a character from the string to compare against the rest
     for(j = i + 1; j < str.length; ++j) { //second loop to compare the above selected character with the rest of the characters in the string
       if(str[i] === str[j]) { // now if there is any character that is equal we set it to false as it is not an isogram
         return false;
       }
     }
   }
   return true; //if the code reaches here, it is an isogram
}
```

There are many other ways to approach this problem. Try finding other solutions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this if you prefer

```
let isIsogram = (str) => str.split("").every((c, i) => str.indexOf(c) == i);

console.log(isIsogram("thomas")); //true
console.log(isIsogram("moses")); //false
console.log(isIsogram("world")); //true
console.log(isIsogram("a b c")); //false(space repeat twice)
```